# php date error, original field of sql date type

Tags: php, datetime, date, recess

in a table user, i have a field birthday which records the birthday of the user. Now, in php, i'm not using sql but recess (a php framework) ORM to insert this record. The original field in the database is of date type.

When I'm using datatime in php i'm getting an error, `not well-formed value encountered.`

from the user, I'm getting a date,month and year as the birthday.

Can someone helps??

Comment: could you post the code which gave the error?

Answer (score 1):

yes if you take date field in db than you can store only date in it should in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

So use `date('Y-m-d')` php function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution :)

In fact, I'm getting the date from the user as YYYY M and D, then contacneting it with #. then, on the server, I'm updating the database like this through the oRM

```
$date=explode("#",filter_var($UpdateDetails->birthday,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); 
$Birthday=date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,(int)$date[1],(int)$date[0],(int)$date[2]));
$User->birthday= strtotime($Birthday);
```

Just if you need to know, that's how I'm retrieving it:

```
$User->birthday=date('Y-F-d',$User->birthday);
```

concerning the format 'Y-F-d', check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more details